# In Tiki I have API to create/update page, time and date of creation does not display properly

Tags: php, tiki-wiki

I have Tiki set up with my php site.

I create/update page using my own Tiki API file but when I show version of page in history tab than creation date is not displayed. Only time is displayed.

This is my code for create page in Tiki.

```
require 'tiki-setup.php';
include_once("tiki-calendar_setup.php");
require_once 'lib/tikilibsohyper.php';
require_once ('lib/userslib.php'); 
include_once ('lib/wiki/histlib.php');
global $tikilib,$calendarlib,$userlib,$histlib;


$tikilib->create_page($pageName, $hits, $pageData, $lastModif, $comment, $username, $ip= '0:0:0:0', $description='' , $lang, $is_html = false, $hash=null, $wysiwyg=NULL, $wiki_authors_style='', $minor=0, $created='');
```

This is for update page

```
$tikilib->update_page($pageName, $pageData, $comment,$username, $ip, $description = '');
```

Now in Tiki history page (TAB) data display as follows:

```
            Information                      Version      Action    

        --------------------------------------------------------------
        2013-03-04 09:47 by administrator       3       v  s  b         
        2013-03-04 09:47 by administrator       2       v  s  b         
        09:32 by administrator                  1       v  s  b
```

First, why it displays only time?
I need both time and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck "Skip date for same day" on the General > Date and Time admin panel.